# Grouping and deleting Files

Tags: python, regex, linux, bash, sorting

I have to come up with a solution to delete all files but the newest 2 in a directory stucture of our owncloud. The be exact - its the file versioning folder. There are files in one folder with the following structure:

`Filename.Ext.v[random_Number]`

The hard part is that there are different files in one folder I need to keep.

IE: Content of folder A:

- HelloWorld.txt.v123
- HelloWorld.txt.v555
- HelloWorld.txt.v666
- OtherFile.pdf.v143
- OtherFile.pdf.v1453
- OtherFile.pdf.v123
- OtherFile.pdf.v14345
- YetOtherFile.docx.v11113

In this case we have 3 "basefiles". And I would have to keep the newest 2 files of each "basefile".

I tried Python3 with `os.walk` and `regex` to filter out the basename. I tried build in Linux tools like `find` with `-ctime`. I could use also bash.

But my real problem is more the logic. How would you approach this task?

**EDIT 2:**
Here my progress:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby
directory = 'C:\\Users\\x41\\Desktop\\Test\\'


def sorted_ls(directory):
    mtime = lambda f: os.stat(os.path.join(directory, f)).st_mtime
    return list(sorted(os.listdir(directory), key=mtime))

print(sorted_ls(directory))

for basename, group in groupby(sorted_ls(directory), lambda x: x.rsplit('.')[0]):
    for i in basename:
            finallist = []
            for a in group:
                finallist.append(a)
            print(finallist[:-2])
```

I am almost there. The function sorts the files in the directory based on the `mtime` value. The suggested `groupby()` function calls my custom sort function.

Now the problem here is that I have to dump the `sort()` before the `groupby()` because this would reset my custom sort. But it now also returns more groups than anticipated.

If my sorted list looks like this:

```
['A.txt.1', 'B.txt.2', 'B.txt.1', 'B.txt.3', 'A.txt.2']
```

I would get 3 groups. A, B, and A again.
Any suggestions?

**FINAL RESULT**

Here is my final version with added recursiveness:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby

directory = r'C:\Users\x41\Desktop\Test'

for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
    output = []
    for basename, group in groupby(sorted(files), lambda x: x.rsplit('.')[0]):
        output.extend(sorted(group, key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(dirpath, x)).st_mtime)[:-2])

        for file in output:
            os.remove(dirpath + "\\" + file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do a simple sort first on the file names so that they are in alphabetical order to allow the `groupby` function to work correctly.

With each of the resulting file groups, you can then sort using your `os.stat` key as follows:

```
import os
from itertools import groupby

directory = r'C:\Users\x41\Desktop\Test'
output = []

for basename, group in groupby(sorted(os.listdir(directory)), lambda x: x.rsplit('.')[0]):
    output.extend(sorted(group, key=lambda x: os.stat(os.path.join(directory, x)).st_mtime)[-2:])

print output
```

This will produce a single list containing the latest two files from each group.

Comment: I updated my code using `groupby()` - but some minor issues are left.

Comment: I think I see what you are trying to do now. I have updated my script.

Answer (score 0):

The logic isn't extremely hard here, if that's the only thing you're looking for.

You'd group files by base name, in a python dictionary for example, where the key is your "base filename" such as "HelloWorld.txt" and the value is a list of all files with the same basename sorted by ctime (or some other metric of time depending on how you define *newest*), and then you delete all files in the list from index 2 onwards accordingly.